# Seaborn stripplot variable marker sizes not working with categories

Tags: python, seaborn, stripplot

I am trying to plot a `stripplot` with 3 categories (column assigned to `x`) and have the marker sizes vary based on a column in a dataframe.

However, the sizes don't line up even when I am setting the `sizes` attribute to the same as `y` (I am using `sizes = df["col"]` as if I use `sizes = "col"` I get the error `TypeError: len() of unsized object`). In doing this, I'd expect to see smaller markers at the bottom and larger markers at the top as the values should be the same for both `sizes` and `y`. Instead there doesn't appear to be any correlation between the size of the marker and its position on the y-axis.

After some investigation by pulling out the `PathCollections` and comparing the actual values (`.get_offsets()` with the size value (`.get_sizes`), it is clear that the same array of sizes is being used for each category.

Is this feature not properly implemented yet? I tried assigning the categories as `hue` instead of `x` but I get a `StopIteration` error. The only solution I've found is to iterate through each category and plot it on a separate axis in a row of axes. This is clunky and surely there's a better way.

Here is a very simplified version of my code:

```py
sns.stripplot(data = df,
              x = 'category_col',
              y = 'value_col',
              sizes = df['value_col'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sns.stripplot` documentation doesn't mention `sizes=` as a possible parameter. The function shares some code with `sns.swarmplot` which relies on all points having the same size. But `hue` should work without problems, at least in the latest version. (In seaborn, hue comes in two flavors: either a limited set of values interpreted as categories with individual colors, or a numerical range which works with color mapping).

Here is how hue could be used, starting from seaborn's 'tips' dataset:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.stripplot(data=tips, x='day', y='total_bill', hue='tip')
sns.despine()
sns.move_legend(ax, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1.02))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.stripplot with hue]

A `scatterplot` doe have `size=` (column to indicate the size of the dots) and `sizes=` (to indicate the range of sizes) parameters. Converting the categorical `x` column to numbers and manually add some jitter, you can create a strip plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips['day'] = tips['day'].astype('category')  # make sure the column uses pandas categorical type
# make a numerical column and add some jitter
tips['day_codes'] = tips['day'].cat.codes + np.random.uniform(-0.3, 0.3, len(tips))

sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x='day_codes', y='total_bill', hue='smoker',
                     size='tip', sizes=(1, 500))
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(tips['day'].cat.categories)), tips['day'].cat.categories)
sns.move_legend(ax, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1.02))
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.scatterplot imitating stripplot]