# increase size difference in bubble plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data set with 5 categories plotted in a bubble plot, similar to this bubble plot below. For two categories the size difference is clearly visible, but for 5 categories the size differnce is harder to spot. So, how can I increase the size difference of my bubbles?

```py
# Modules #
import seaborn
from matplotlib import pyplot

# Plot #
tips = seaborn.load_dataset("tips")
axes = seaborn.scatterplot(x="day", y="tip", size="sex", hue="time", data=tips)

# Legend split and place outside #
num_of_colors   = len(tips['time'].unique()) + 1
handles, labels = axes.get_legend_handles_labels()
color_hl = handles[:num_of_colors], labels[:num_of_colors]
sizes_hl = handles[num_of_colors:], labels[num_of_colors:]

# Call legend twice #
color_leg = axes.legend(*color_hl,
                        bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 1),
                        loc            = 'upper left',
                        borderaxespad  = 0.)
sizes_leg = axes.legend(*sizes_hl,
                        bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 0),
                        loc            = 'lower left',
                        borderaxespad  = 0.)

# We need this because the 2nd call to legend() erases the first #
axes.add_artist(color_leg)

# Adjust #
pyplot.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

# Display #
pyplot.ion()
pyplot.show()
```

source: [separate-seaborn-legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456956/separate-seaborn-legend-into-two-distinct-boxes)[image]

Comment: In `seaborn.scatterplot(....)`, can you not add `sizes=(10, 500)`... where 10 is min size and 500 is max size for eg?

Comment: See also [Seaborn stripplot variable marker sizes not working with categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75540274/) where a scatter plot is used to simulate a strip plot.